# Email Service without SSL/TLS found

Tags: office365

our security scan reported the finding that is the posting title.

I am trying to look into how to resolve this and online articles point to having to enable SMTP Auth in order to enable SSL/TLS: [https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/office-365-smtp/#:~:text=SMTP%20Server%3A%20smtp.office365.,Requires%20SSL%3A%20Yes](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/office-365-smtp/#:%7E:text=SMTP%20Server%3A%20smtp.office365.,Requires%20SSL%3A%20Yes)

Microsft advises against using SMTP Auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission

Is there another way that SSL/TLS should be enabled with Office365? Or is this an outdated finding that doesn't apply anymore?